# dplyr::failwith doesn't work with lme4::lmer but does with lm

Tags: r, dplyr, lme4

I had a workflow that used to work with `do`, `failwith` and `lmer`. Now it seems to be broken.
What I am doing works with `lm` so I wonder if it is a bug or I need to change something.

**This works:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

lmer(   Yield ~ 1|Batch, Dyestuff, REML = FALSE)
lm(   Yield ~ Batch, Dyestuff)
```

**But this does not for `lmer` but does for `lm`:**

```
lmer_fw    <- failwith(NULL,lmer   ,quiet=TRUE)
lm_fw      <- failwith(NULL,lm   ,  quiet=TRUE)

lmer_fw(Yield ~ 1|Batch, Dyestuff, REML = FALSE)
lm_fw(  Yield ~ Batch, Dyestuff)
```

`nest::possible` has same behaviour.

Any ideas?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lme4_1.1-12         Matrix_1.2-7.1      dplyr_0.5.0         RevoUtilsMath_8.0.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7      lattice_0.20-34  assertthat_0.1   MASS_7.3-45      grid_3.3.1       R6_2.1.3         nlme_3.1-128     DBI_0.5-1       
 [9] magrittr_1.5     minqa_1.2.4      nloptr_1.0.4     splines_3.3.1    RevoUtils_10.0.1 tools_3.3.1      tibble_1.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same issue as https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/369 , which I had fixed on a branch but just now got around to pulling into the main development version.  If you install the devel version (1.1-13) via `devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")` it should work now.  (If you need a binary version, let the maintainers know ...)